# Qt and C++ game development for assignment

Tags: c++, qt, pacman

I've got the assignment to write a pacman game using qt creator and c++. I know that QT Quick is better suited for games but i've got no option. The only problem is i am a little bit lost because the documentation of qt is great but there is massive amount of it. Could you provide me some tutorials or links to the documentation where to start?
I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Try to give a look at the QGraphisView and the Animation framework examples, probably they are a good starting point.